# Extend dataframe using data_range for every start, end date

Tags: python, pandas

Consider data that contains employer-employee links with start and end date.

```
   employer  employee      start        end
0         0         0 2007-01-01 2007-12-31
1         1        86 2007-01-01 2007-12-31
2         1        63 2007-06-01 2007-12-31
3         1        93 2007-01-01 2007-12-31
```

Now I want to "spread" the date, that is create one observation for every month between `start` and `end`. I thought that

```
def extend(x):
    index = pd.date_range(start=x['start'], end=x['end'], freq='M')
    df = pd.DataFrame([x.values], index=index, columns=x.index)
    return df

long = df.apply(extend, axis=1)
```

would do the trick, however, it only contains the indices:

```
>>> long.head()
Out[245]: 
   employer  employee  start  end
0  employer  employee  start  end
1  employer  employee  start  end
```

When I was testing this with the first row, however, this worked:

```
>>> extend(df.iloc[0])
Out[246]: 
            employer  employee      start        end
2007-01-31         0         0 2007-01-01 2007-12-31
2007-02-28         0         0 2007-01-01 2007-12-31
2007-03-31         0         0 2007-01-01 2007-12-31
(...)
```

What am I doing wrong? And perhaps, is there a better way of doing this? My final goal is to get output as the previous one, however formatted as `employer employee month year`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is `apply` expects to return the same number of rows as the input.

You could do it with `iterrows` and a list comprehension without much modifications of your code:

```
def extend(x):
    index = pd.date_range(start=x['start'], end=x['end'], freq='M')
    df = pd.DataFrame([x.values], index=index, columns=x.index)
    return df

>>> new = pd.concat([extend(x) for _,x in df.iterrows()])
>>> new

            employer  employee      start        end
2007-01-31         0         0 2007-01-01 2007-12-31
2007-02-28         0         0 2007-01-01 2007-12-31
2007-03-31         0         0 2007-01-01 2007-12-31
2007-04-30         0         0 2007-01-01 2007-12-31
2007-05-31         0         0 2007-01-01 2007-12-31
2007-06-30         0         0 2007-01-01 2007-12-31
2007-07-31         0         0 2007-01-01 2007-12-31
2007-08-31         0         0 2007-01-01 2007-12-31
2007-09-30         0         0 2007-01-01 2007-12-31
2007-10-31         0         0 2007-01-01 2007-12-31
2007-11-30         0         0 2007-01-01 2007-12-31
2007-12-31         0         0 2007-01-01 2007-12-31
2007-01-31         1        86 2007-01-01 2007-12-31
2007-02-28         1        86 2007-01-01 2007-12-31
2007-03-31         1        86 2007-01-01 2007-12-31
2007-04-30         1        86 2007-01-01 2007-12-31
2007-05-31         1        86 2007-01-01 2007-12-31
2007-06-30         1        86 2007-01-01 2007-12-31
2007-07-31         1        86 2007-01-01 2007-12-31
2007-08-31         1        86 2007-01-01 2007-12-31
2007-09-30         1        86 2007-01-01 2007-12-31
2007-10-31         1        86 2007-01-01 2007-12-31
2007-11-30         1        86 2007-01-01 2007-12-31
2007-12-31         1        86 2007-01-01 2007-12-31
2007-06-30         1        63 2007-06-01 2007-12-31
2007-07-31         1        63 2007-06-01 2007-12-31
2007-08-31         1        63 2007-06-01 2007-12-31
2007-09-30         1        63 2007-06-01 2007-12-31
2007-10-31         1        63 2007-06-01 2007-12-31
2007-11-30         1        63 2007-06-01 2007-12-31
2007-12-31         1        63 2007-06-01 2007-12-31
2007-01-31         1        93 2007-01-01 2007-12-31
2007-02-28         1        93 2007-01-01 2007-12-31
2007-03-31         1        93 2007-01-01 2007-12-31
2007-04-30         1        93 2007-01-01 2007-12-31
2007-05-31         1        93 2007-01-01 2007-12-31
2007-06-30         1        93 2007-01-01 2007-12-31
2007-07-31         1        93 2007-01-01 2007-12-31
2007-08-31         1        93 2007-01-01 2007-12-31
2007-09-30         1        93 2007-01-01 2007-12-31
2007-10-31         1        93 2007-01-01 2007-12-31
2007-11-30         1        93 2007-01-01 2007-12-31
2007-12-31         1        93 2007-01-01 2007-12-31
```

You could also do it with a `groupby/apply` since it is more flexible. So something like the following:

```
def extend(x):
    x = x.iloc[0,:]
    dates = pd.date_range(start=x['start'], end=x['end'], freq='M')
    return pd.DataFrame(dates,columns=['date'])

>>> long = df.groupby(['employer','employee'])[['start','end']].apply(extend)
>>> long

                           date
employer employee
0        0        0  2007-01-31
                  1  2007-02-28
                  2  2007-03-31
                  3  2007-04-30
                  4  2007-05-31
                  5  2007-06-30
                  6  2007-07-31
                  7  2007-08-31
                  8  2007-09-30
                  9  2007-10-31
                  10 2007-11-30
                  11 2007-12-31
1        63       0  2007-06-30
                  1  2007-07-31
                  2  2007-08-31
                  3  2007-09-30
                  4  2007-10-31
                  5  2007-11-30
                  6  2007-12-31
         86       0  2007-01-31
                  1  2007-02-28
                  2  2007-03-31
                  3  2007-04-30
                  4  2007-05-31
                  5  2007-06-30
                  6  2007-07-31
                  7  2007-08-31
                  8  2007-09-30
                  9  2007-10-31
                  10 2007-11-30
                  11 2007-12-31
         93       0  2007-01-31
                  1  2007-02-28
                  2  2007-03-31
                  3  2007-04-30
                  4  2007-05-31
                  5  2007-06-30
                  6  2007-07-31
                  7  2007-08-31
                  8  2007-09-30
                  9  2007-10-31
                  10 2007-11-30
                  11 2007-12-31
```

Or could iterate over the rows concat

Comment: The second answer is not fail save as there are potentially multiple lines per `employer, employee` tuple. However, the first one works like a charm.